# SSRS report calculate field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a requirement of creating an ssrs report that needs to be showed in a matrix in this format

Dataset includes the following fields

year, month, values, account name

report format is something like this:

```
            current month |   month ( last year)| difference in % 
account name
```

how do I calculate field for month of previous year? because SSRs does not have case or where logic inbuilt?

Comment: Add the month from the previous year as a column to your dataset. That way it is straightforward to get the % difference between them in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in your dataset you can do

```
 DATEADD(YY,-1,COLUMN)
```

This will change your date a year back.

If you want to do this in the Report Side You can create a new column and create a calculated field and use:

```
 =DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,ColumnName)
```

Same Effect